# Android libraries and resources

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-context

I have a main application and a library, both as Android projects in eclipse. I added the library to the main application.

The problem is I'm trying to access some resources from the Manifest of the main application from one of the classes of the library, and it doesn't work. I am even using the main application context but still gives me error. This is what it says:

```
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage.name/mypackage.name.MainActivity}:     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266):    at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266):    at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 21:04:33.808: E/AndroidRuntime(31266):    at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
```

And here the code:

```
public AndroidPopup(Activity c)
    {
        gameName = c.getString(c.getApplicationInfo().labelRes);
...
 }
```

What is going on? The argument is the main activity from where I want to extract the values...

EDIT: Ok, now I have realised that even if I try to get those resources in the main application, they crash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly access resources from the main app in the library. What I did in a similar situation is to define a method in the library that doesn't do anything but is used in the library code

```
public string getLabelRes()
{
    return null;
}
```

and create a class in the main app that inherits from your library class where you actually get the resource:

```
@Override
public string getLabelRes()
{
    return c.getString(c.getApplicationInfo().labelRes);
}
```

This solution allows you to reuse the same library in many apps in an object oriented way.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that labelRes is equal to 0, and I'm pretty sure if you use it in the code of your application, you'll have same problem.

You better use this :

```
public AndroidPopup(Activity c){
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = c.getApplicationInfo();
    String gameName = (String) c.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
    // ...
}
```